# Java version of the Java Library in Lotus Domino Designer

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to use enums in the java library (not xPages!) in my application. But every java library that I create, is being compiled with java 1.3 (there is a field called $JavaCompilerSource in Java Library properties). But I have configured whole workspace of my designer and even this particular application to use java 1.5.

The funny thing is, that there is another library in one of my applications, which uses enums and is being compiled with java 1.5. Somehow I've done it a few months ago. But I don't know how. I can use this library via copy&paste&rename, but it's not a good way.

Does anyone know, how to do it?
Thanks, JiKra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found a solution.
There is a parameter in **notes.ini**.

```
JavaCompilerTarget=1.5
```

This java duality in Notes is just sick.

Comment: I guess you saw this?: [Using enum singleton coding pattern in a Domino Java Agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415217/using-enum-singleton-coding-pattern-in-a-domino-java-agent)

Comment: Actualy I found it here: http://lekkimworld.com/2007/08/27/discovering_notes_8_enabling_java_5_source_compilation.html