# Domino: Webservice: Class do not have a property of the name

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf, lotus-domino, wsdl2java

I have the following Problem.

I tried to create a web service `a standard cmis Webservice Interface` on IBM, Domino with wsdl2java (with cxf). After creating all java classes I tried to get answers from the webservice with the eclipse Java Client. It works find. After this test I import the generated java classes into a Domino Database. 
Now I have the problem to run the webservice, because the following error message:

> class org.oasis_open.docs.ns.cmis.messaging._200908.GetTypeDefinition
>   **do not have a property of the name** {URL..}repositoryId

In the JAVA Class the following code:

```
public class GetTypeDefinition {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String repositoryId;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String typeId;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "extension", namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<CmisExtensionType> extension;
```

The Domino JAVA Env. does not understand the Tag `@XmlElement(required = true)` without the name, namespace and the type definition.

If I add in the same line the following code:

```
@XmlElement(required = true, name = "repositoryId", namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/", type = String.class)
    protected String repositoryId;
```

it works (error then in the next line:

> GetTypeDefinition do not have a property of the name {URL}typeId

Now the question is: why? Can I generate the java classes with an other tool (not with cxf wsdl2java) or do I need other parameters to get the complete code?
In the generated JAVA Classes are round about 170 lines with the problematic code.
Have somebody an Idea to solve the problem on the Domino Server (x64 9.0)?

Comment: What version of SOAP and expected JVM version? (see you mentioned Server already)

Comment: cxf  2.5.7
JVM 6 (IBM J9)

Comment: So you are not using Domino WS functionality. Instead 3rd party jars?

Comment: Yes because Domino WS Providers does not work and the wsdl file can not import into the client. I get an error message without any informations so I tried to generate the JAVA Code with cxf wsdl2java to use it with XPages and Java. Today I tried to generate the classes with Java6 jdk but cxf wsdl2java generates an error message. Now I do not have any Idea to solve this problems.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415217/using-enum-singleton-coding-pattern-in-a-domino-java-agent

Comment: No, I don't use an Agent. In the Client the Java Version is set to 1.6. I'm using XPages to run the methodes of the Webservice Java classes.

Comment: That sets the JVM level for everything, not just Agents.

Comment: It does not work. The compiler has no problems. Only the run on server throw the exception. I think I need to generate the java classes with a lower version of JAVA. What do you think?

Comment: Other things to test. Move jars out of NSF to lib/ext folder on server. Set agent to security level 2 or 3.

Comment: The problem was solved.
Generating of ExtenstionService with cxf 2.0.13
Generating of RepositoryService with cxf 2.1
The generated classes work with the Domino Server.
Thanks a lot you your help!

Comment: Write your answer as an answer (and more detail if needed) and mark your question answered. Thanks.